# Is it possible to redirect content calls in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm experimenting with javascript and css caching in ASP.NET MVC.  Is it possible to intercept calls to the server for these types of files?

For example, if a request gets to the server for

~/Scripts/Something.CurrentVersion.js

I would like to intercept this call and tell the server to return

~/Scripts/SomeOtherFile.js

Would it be possible to hook into some event or create a new module or HttpHandler to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout these links for different ways:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/28/script-and-css-management-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/05/02/script-and-css-management-in-asp-net-mvc-part-2.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/combineMinify.aspx

Comment: Thanks - just one last question - if I use the same approach as in the codeproject article, would it still impact deployment into IIS like mfeingold mentioned?

Comment: @www.jacopretorius.net : It is not an HttpHandler. So no it wont.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. HttpHandler is certainly one way to go. Beware of the integration to IIS though - to have full control over mapping you have to run it in integrated mode - otherwise IIS itself will process request BEFORE it will get to the worker process

Comment: So what would be the recommended way?  Do you perhaps have any example to get started with?